# automation testing by selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i have too many usernames and passwords in a txt file and i want to use  them in a test script , the password many contain (:) and  the error is (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)) how to fix this and how to get the data from the txt file and use them in the test .

the txt look like this

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
user3:password
username5:password6
testit:passtest
```

etc

i tried many codes to read the txt file and use it to login no luck .

login do some tasks and logout and repeat the process with  the rest accounts

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    from getpass import getpass
    import time

#login username & password

with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        user, password = line.split(':')


#define what browser & website
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(('https://example.com'))
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginRegisterTabs']/ul/li[1]")
elem.click()

emailelement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div/input")
emailelement.send_keys('user')
passelement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div[2]/div/input")
passelement.send_keys('password')
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/p/button[1]/span")
elem.click()

#server login
time.sleep(1)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='joinGame']/button/span[1]")
elem.click()

#Active Daily
time.sleep(1)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='multiPopup']/div[2]/div[2]/a")
elem.click()


#menu
time.sleep(4)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*//*[@id='GF_toolbar']/ul/li[5]/a")
elem.click()

#Vmod Menu
time.sleep(2)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='vacationMode']/div[1]/div/a")
elem.click()

#Active Vmod
time.sleep(2)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='options_umod_confirm']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")
elem.click()
```

Comment: You are only accessing the last username and password. Th old ones get replaced by the new ones

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error you're getting, that can help to understand your issue

Comment: Your sample txt file does not have even one password that contains the `:` character. If it did, and you had an entry like "userA:pass:word" and you tried to `line.split(':')` this, how many element would you get? This problem has nothing to do with Selenium. If you had created an [mcve], you would find that it is purely a Python problem.

Comment: the problem in here : 
passelement.send_keys('pass')
emailelement.send_keys('user')

hes sending user as username and pass as password 
he  won't use the txt file

Answer (score 2):

1. Limit number of splits in user/password strings:

   `user, password = line.split(':', 1)`
2. Move everything under this line under the `for` loop (iterating over the file lines)